# Counting every word in a text file only once using python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, iteration, defaultdict

I have a small python script I am working on for a class homework assignment. The script reads a file and prints the 10 most frequent and infrequent words and their frequencies. For this assignment, a word is defined as 2 letters or more. I have the word frequencies working just fine, however the third part of the assignment is to print the total number of **unique** words in the document. Unique words meaning count every word in the document, **only once.**

Without changing my current script too much, how can I count all the words in the document only one time?

**p.s. I am using Python 2.6 so please don't mention the use of collections.Counter**

```
from string import punctuation
from collections import defaultdict
import re

number = 10
words = {}
total_unique = 0
words_only = re.compile(r'^[a-z]{2,}$')
counter = defaultdict(int)


"""Define words as 2+ letters"""
def count_unique(s):
    count = 0
    if word in line:
        if len(word) >= 2:
            count += 1
    return count


"""Open text document, read it, strip it, then filter it"""
txt_file = open('charactermask.txt', 'r')

for line in txt_file:
    for word in line.strip().split():
        word = word.strip(punctuation).lower()
        if words_only.match(word):
               counter[word] += 1


# Most Frequent Words
top_words = sorted(counter.iteritems(),
                    key=lambda(word, count): (-count, word))[:number] 

print "Most Frequent Words: "

for word, frequency in top_words:
    print "%s: %d" % (word, frequency)


# Least Frequent Words:
least_words = sorted(counter.iteritems(),
                    key=lambda (word, count): (count, word))[:number]

print " "
print "Least Frequent Words: "

for word, frequency in least_words:
    print "%s: %d" % (word, frequency)


# Total Unique Words:
print " "
print "Total Number of Unique Words: %s " % total_unique
```

Comment: Number of keys in the `counter` dictionary?

Comment: Is this different from [Retrieving total number of words with 2 or more letters in a document using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482844) that you asked yesterday?

Comment: yes, this is different. read the questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the number of `key`s in your `counter` dictionary:

```
total_unique = len(counter.keys())
```

Or more simply:

```
total_unique = len(counter)
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Thank you! I'm just learning Python so forgive me for posting such a low level question.

Answer (score 2):

A `defaultdict` is great, but it might be more that what you need. You will need it for the part about most frequent words. But in the absence of that question, using a `defaultdict` is overkill. In such a situation, I would suggest using a `set` instead:

```
words = set()
for line in txt_file:
    for word in line.strip().split():
        word = word.strip(punctuation).lower()
        if words_only.match(word):
               words.add(word)
num_unique_words = len(words)
```

Now `words` contains only unique words.

I am only posting this because you say that you are new to python, so I want to make sure that you are aware of `set`s as well. Again, for your purposes, a `defaultdict` works fine and is justified

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know I could use a set in this purpose